# On the SonarQube issues page, how do I filter OUT violations of a specific rule?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube v6.7.3.  I find it hard to understand how to define effective display filters on the Issues page.  For instance, in the current list of >1000 issues, I'd like to remove from the list all occurrences of a particular violation (and others).  I see that there is filter functionality, but I don't understand how it works, or how to do what I'm looking for.  I've found some official SonarQube documentation, and even a page that describes issues, but it's very rudimentary and doesn't describe filters.

Comment: I've answered your question. If it resolves your question, , please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are looking for the issues which are marked are violated against a quality profile rule.

If so, then here are the thing you need to do.

1. Try to understand the **RULE**, **Quality Profile** and **Quality Gates.**
2. Rule is subset of Quality gates
3. Quality Profile is subset of Quality Gates.

So, now coming back to the rules and violations.

You can see what are the rules present on your sonar server by going to **Rules** tab in the dashboard.

So, every quality profile will have many rules and many quality profiles will have many more rules. But, you can understand what is that rule and to which Profile it belongs to as shown in the below image.

[image]

Now all you have to do is, get into the Project analysis, Switch to issues tab, if your project has many languages used then select an individual language, and then select the rules, and then categorize the specific violations. See below image for more info.

[image]